# I'm not quite sure if the Big O of my algorithm is O(n^3) or O( m * n * n )

Tags: c, big-o, nested-loops

So, I'm trying to find the Big O of my algorithm below.

```
for(int x=0;x<m;x++){
    for(int y=0;y<n;y++){
        for(int z=0;z<n;z++){
            if(target[x][y]==source[z]) count++;
        }
    }
}
```

But, I'm not quite sure if it's O(n^3) or O( m * n * n )...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like it's **O(m*n*n)**, which is **O(m*n<sup>2</sup>)**, since your outer loop is iterating over `m`, but your two inner loops are each iterating over `n`.

Answer (score 3):

Each loop is independent of the others except for being nested, so it's a simple multiplication of the number of passes each does: O(m * n * n) = O(m * n<sup>2</sup>).

This means the performance will scale linearly as `m` increases, and quadratically as `n` increases. If both increase, the performance will scale by their product.

Unless there's some unstated relationship between `m` and `n`, this can't be generalized into O(n<sup>3</sup>). Quite the opposite, if there is no relationship, you could even consider the algorithm O(m) (if you're not interested in what happens when `n` is scaled) or O(n<sup>2</sup>) (if you're not interested in what happens when `m` is scaled).

---

Note that this kind of search can be done in O(m + n<sup>2</sup>).

1. Create a set.
2. For each of the `m` elements of `source`,

   1. Let's call `s` the value of the current element.
   2. If the set doesn't contains `s`,

      1. Add `s` to the set.
3. For each element of the `n*n` elements of `target`,

   1. Let's call `v` the value of the current element.
   2. If the set contains `s`,

      1. Add one to `count`.

This assumes that set lookups are O(1) and that adding to the set is O(1) (amortized).

Answer (score 0):

loop O(n).
loop inside loop O(n*n) or O(n^2).
loop inside loop inside another loop O(n*n*n) or O(n^3).

Is your outermost loop dependent from n or m? For sure you cannot just neglect outer loop as there was none.

Therefore O(m*n*n) from your three loops inside each other.